# Custom IBM Watson Visual Recognition service integration with Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I created and trained a custom visual recognition model on IBM Cloud. I want to connect it to my application which I am building using Flutter. I looked at the IBM API document reference below and everything worked well but it doesn't talk about connecting it to your application.

> https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition/visual-recognition-v3#classify-images

I tried using the **flutter_ibm_watson** package from pub.dev (the package is severely outdated and has many issues but I still tried it anyway). I plugged in my API key and URL but it didn't even output the result of the image from the classifiers. It just identified what the image was (e.g. skyscraper image returned 'skyscraper').

```
IamOptions options = await IamOptions(iamApiKey: "NRDjngCby2d-pSHOPyWQJxhuB6vOY2uOTCX6KV2BCfwB", url: "https://api.us-south.visual-recognition.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/ef286f4e-84c7-44e0-b63d-a6a49a142a30").build();
VisualRecognition visualRecognition = new VisualRecognition(iamOptions: options, language: Language.ENGLISH); // Language.ENGLISH is language response
ClassifiedImages classifiedImages = await visualRecognition.classifyImageUrl("https://starindojaya.com/images/products/PAPER_CUP_PAPERCUP_2_OZ.jpg");
print(classifiedImages.getImages()[0].getClassifiers()[0].getClasses()[0].className);
```

I also downloaded the CoreML file as stated in the API docs but am unsure of what to do with it. On the side note, I did get my application to connect to my custom visual recognition model through the StreamMyClassifier class in Flutter and it worked very well. However, I also wanted the "confidence" score as well in order to display to the user as well. I would appreciate it if you could help. Anything helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your print command is printing the classname of the top class, of the top classifier of the 1st image that you have submitted. So writing `skyscraper` is working as it should. If you want all the classifiers then modify your print to:

```
print(classifiedImages.getImages()[0].getClassifiers());
```

If you have a custom classifier then you need to pass in a parameter to tell the service. You can do this by either setting the parameter `owner` to `me` or setting `classifier_ids` to include your classier id. Both are arrays so remember to wrap them in `[]`. If you specify both then `classifier_ids` take preference.

You use the Core ML model to run Visual Recognition on iOS / MacOS devices with Apple Core ML. Typically developed with Swift on Xcode.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. My visual model has nothing to do with classifying images like skyscrapers. I just used that as a test image. My model is supposed to classify if an object is recyclable, compost, or landfill. However, every time I plug in an image, like a paper cup, I just get paper cup, so it seems that I'm just using the general visual image classifier from IBM. Thanks

Comment: See my amended answer.

Comment: Sorry I was offline for quite a while. Can you please rewrite the statement in a comment as to what you mean by owner and me and classifier ids?

Comment: I don't recognise the SDK that you are using, so am unable to tell you how to pass in the `owner` parameter. If you use one of the ibm-watson SDKS then the API docs have examples that show how - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition/visual-recognition-v3?code=node#classify